# Binding a two dimensional array to the texture memory of a GPU with cudaBindTexture2D produces an error

Tags: c, cuda

I am trying to execute a kernel in a compute capability 1.3 GPU using the CUDA API. Binding one dimensional arrays works as expected but the following code produces an error:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define checkCudaErrors(err)           __checkCudaErrors (err, __FILE__, __LINE__)

inline static void __checkCudaErrors( cudaError err, const char *file, const int line )     {

    if( cudaSuccess != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s(%i) : CUDA Runtime API error %d: %s.\n", file, line, (int)err, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
        exit(-1);
    }
}

texture<int, cudaTextureType2D> tex_transition;

int main ( void ) {

    int m = 8, p_size = 100, alphabet = 20;

    size_t pitch;

    int *transition = ( int * ) malloc ( ( m * p_size + 1 ) * alphabet * sizeof ( int ) );
    memset ( transition, -1, ( m * p_size + 1 ) * alphabet * sizeof ( int ) );

    int *d_transition;

    checkCudaErrors ( cudaMallocPitch ( &d_transition, &pitch, alphabet * sizeof ( int ), ( m * p_size + 1 ) ) );

    checkCudaErrors ( cudaMemcpy2D ( d_transition, pitch, transition, alphabet * sizeof ( int ), alphabet * sizeof ( int ), ( m * p_size + 1 ), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );

    cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<int>();
    checkCudaErrors ( cudaBindTexture2D ( 0, tex_transition, d_transition, desc, alphabet * sizeof ( int ), ( m * p_size + 1 ), pitch ) );

    cudaFree ( d_transition );

    return 0;
}
```

When executing i get the error "test.cu(33) : CUDA Runtime API error 11: invalid argument.
". By setting alphabet to 10 the error goes away. If i am not mistaken, each array bound to textures can have a maximum size of 65000 x 65000 words (in this case integers) but the *transition* array is far smaller.

Comment: It is the call to cudaBindTexture2D()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one of the arguments in the cudaBindTexture2D calls wrong. The dimensions of the texture are in *texel* units, not bytes, so the call should be:

```
cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<int>();
cudaBindTexture2D ( 0, 
                    tex_transition, 
                    d_transition, desc, 
                    alphabet,            // in texels
                    ( m * p_size + 1 ),  // in texels
                    pitch );
```

The byte width is only necessary in the allocation call. The texture bind uses the pitch argument to work out the memory layout of the 2D allocation.

Comment: This seems to be true only for cudaBindTexture2D()?. If i understand correctly, the one-dimensional cudaBindTexture() function requires the size in bytes.

Comment: Yes the 1D texture size is specified in bytes